# Pythons equivalent of Perl's HTTP::Proxy module

Tags: python, perl

I am porting a Perl project that uses HTTP::Proxy module (which itself uses the HTTP::Daemon, HTTP::Proxy::Engine, LWP and a couple of other modules) to implement a proxy server that is capable of filtering requests, managing users,...
I looked up PyPI but i didn't found anything like this module. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/

Comment: An example of a Proxy Server in Twisted: http://wiki.python.org/moin/Twisted-Examples